# Force install fail with message using WiX Bundle MBA

Tags: wix

I'm taking over this project and don't have access to the person who set it up initially. Currently the bundle has .net4 included. The desire is to remove the file and make the end user download .net manually. I'm trying to set the bundle up to check the installed .net version (if any), display a details message with a download link if it doesn't meet the reqs then abort the install and close.

Every time I try to remove the variables that point to the .net package I get build errors. This is what I have so far.

```
        <Chain>
      <PackageGroupRef Id='Netfx4Full' />
      <MsiPackage  SourceFile="$(var.TargetDir)Client.msi" Id="Client" Cache="no" Visible="no" ForcePerMachine="yes">
        <MsiProperty Name="INSTALLDIR" Value="[InstallFolder]"/>
      </MsiPackage>   
    </Chain>
  </Bundle>
  <Fragment>
    <PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK40FULL"/>
    <Variable Name="InstallationPath" bal:Overridable="yes" />
    <WixVariable Id="WixMbaPrereqPackageId" Value="Netfx4Full" />
    <WixVariable Id="WixMbaPrereqLicenseUrl" Value="NetfxLicense.rtf" />
    <Variable Name="DisplayVersion" Value="$(var.BundleVersion)" />
    <util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full" Value="Version" Variable="Netfx4FullVersion" />
    <util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full" Value="Version" Variable="Netfx4x64FullVersion" Win64="yes" />

    <Condition Message="This application requires .NET Framework 4.0. Please install the .NET Framework then run this installer again.">
      <![CDATA[Installed OR NETFRAMEWORK40]]>
    </Condition>

    <PackageGroup Id="Netfx4Full">
      <ExePackage Id="Netfx4Full" Cache="no" PerMachine="yes" Permanent="yes" Vital="yes" Compressed="no"
                  SourceFile="DotNetInstallers/dotnetfx40_full_x86_x64.exe"
                  DownloadUrl="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=164193"
                  DetectCondition="Netfx4FullVersion OR Netfx4x64FullVersion">  
    </ExePackage>
    </PackageGroup>
  </Fragment>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why would you pull the .NET package out of the bundle?  One of the major features of a bundle is to deliver your product along with all of its prerequisites in a single exe.

Comment: It's what the client wants. It's mainly a file size consideration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on these lines, it looks like you're using the ManagedBootstrapperApplicationHost.

```
<WixVariable Id="WixMbaPrereqPackageId" Value="Netfx4Full" />
<WixVariable Id="WixMbaPrereqLicenseUrl" Value="NetfxLicense.rtf" />
```

The ManagedBootstrapperApplicationHost is the builtin way in WiX to use a custom BootstrapperApplication built in .NET (a managed BA, or MBA).  The MBAHost requires you to package .NET in your bundle.  If you're concerned about the size of your bundle, then you can use the NetFx4Web package in the WixNetFxExtension.  This will make the bundle download the web installer at runtime.  You can customize the user interface that appears while installing .NET using mbapreq.thm and mbapreq.wxl.

Comment: I was able to get the client to download the .net package without having it bundled. Now that you have pointed me in the direction of these files, maybe I can halt the install and get it localized. Thanks for the help!